# How to implement an Iterator for a trait object

Tags: rust

I am trying to create an Iterator for a trait that allows trait objects. My extremely simplified and contrived example would be something like this:

```rust
trait MyTrait<T>
where
    T: 'static,
{
    fn store(&mut self, t: T);

    fn access(&self, i: usize) -> T;

    fn iter(&self) -> MyIter<T> {
        MyIter::new(self)
    }
}

struct MyIter<'a, T: 'static> {
    collection: &'a dyn MyTrait<T>,
    j: usize,
}

impl<'a, T: 'static> MyIter<'a, T> {
    fn new(collection: &dyn MyTrait<T>) -> Self {
        Self {
            collection: collection,
            j: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'static> Iterator for MyIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.j += 1;
        Some(self.collection.access(self.j))
    }
}
```

but this gives

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |         MyIter::new(self)
   |                     ^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = note: required for the cast from `Self` to the object type `dyn MyTrait<T>`
help: consider further restricting `Self`
   |
9  |     fn iter(&self) -> MyIter<T> where Self: Sized {
```

Now, I understand that the compiler wants `Self` to be `Sized` and I could just add the where clause. However, I would like to implement `MyTrait` for other traits that are not `Sized`. In fact, as they need to be object traits, I cannot add `Sized`. How could I accomplish that.

Whatever I try, I run into a `Sized` problem. Is there a general solution or a tutorial for implementing Iterators in rust? Unfortunately, the only examples I have found are either iterators for structs or use unsafe code. As the `Sized` requirement is for the casting to dyn ... even boxing dyn ... won't be a solution as far as I can tell.

Comment: Would `IntoIterator` work? That would seem more idiomatic to me.

Comment: @Mgetz, I don't think this would solve my problem in general, the question remains - and maybe I should have put it like this - how to pass `self` to an iterator implementation (whatever kind of iterator) when self is not a struct but a trait object and so is unsized.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if `Self` is, for example, a trait object, then `&Self` is a wide pointer (two words), and we cannot convert it to trait object because we need more indirection for that (we don't have where to store the metadata).

A possible solution is to use generics instead of trait objects, but if you do want trait objects, you can use `Box` to create another indirection:

```rust
trait MyTrait<T>
where
    T: 'static,
{
    fn store(&mut self, t: T);

    fn access(&self, i: usize) -> T;

    fn iter(&self) -> MyIter<T> {
        MyIter::new(Box::new(IterRefAdapter(self)))
    }
}

struct IterRefAdapter<'a, U: ?Sized>(&'a U);

impl<U: ?Sized + MyTrait<T>, T: 'static> MyTrait<T> for IterRefAdapter<'_, U> {
    fn store(&mut self, t: T) {
        panic!("cannot call `store()` via shared reference");
    }

    fn access(&self, i: usize) -> T {
        U::access(self.0, i)
    }
}

struct MyIter<'a, T: 'static> {
    collection: Box<dyn MyTrait<T> + 'a>,
    j: usize,
}

impl<'a, T: 'static> MyIter<'a, T> {
    fn new(collection: Box<dyn MyTrait<T> + 'a>) -> Self {
        Self { collection, j: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'static> Iterator for MyIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.j += 1;
        Some(self.collection.access(self.j))
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I haven't managed to get this fully working yet. When I try to use it (and implement for a simple struct for testing), I get ``error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `<IterRefAdapter<'_, IterRefAdapt...>>>>>>>>> as MyTrait<i32>>::iter` `` I would like to use generics but it is complicated enough without that added, at least until trait aliases are generally available.

Comment: @user1885616 The code I gave works (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a68105f1a3c2e89d52874d61ca0f078). Maybe if you post your code I'll be able to help.